# Menu bar next to logo (CSS)

Tags: html, css, menu

I would like to have the menu bar next to the logo (same level). What should I do? Please see screenshot.

Many thanks for your help.

[baner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pz9p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrap everything in one div and put every list under one `ul`.If you intend to put image in place of logo simply put `img` tag

```
<style>
.ar{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

// for demo
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border:solid black 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ar">
<nav>
<ul>
<li>logo</li>
<li>home</li>
<li>application</li>
<li>news</li>
<li>about</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in a div so they are next to each other.
So instead of doing it separately, put it into one div.
If that doesn't work, you'd have to position it, using

```
*elementname* {
   position:relative;
   right:-200px;
   top:-150px;
}
```

You can further adjust it to your liking

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your two elements into a flex container

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

// for demo
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    Your logo here
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>link 1</li>
      <li>link 2</li>
      <li>link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make the logo and the navigation menu both `inline-block`, so they don't push each other to a new line.

```css
header>#logo,
header>nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    LOGO HERE
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```